# Microsoft graph API create recurring event in universal timezone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create recurring event. below is my json:

```
{
    "eventStartDateTime":"2023-06-18T20:30:00.000",
    "eventEndDateTime":"2023-06-18T21:00:00.000"
    "recurrence": { 
        "pattern": {
            "type":"Weekly",
            "dayOfMonth":0,
            "interval":1,
            "daysOfWeek":[
              "Monday",
              "Wednesday"
            ],
            "index":"",
            "month":0,
            "firstDayOfWeek":"Sunday"
         },
        "range": { 
             "type":"EndDate",
             "startDate":"2023-06-18",
             "endDate":"2023-12-12",
             "numberOfOccurrences":0
         }
     }
}
```

When I look into graph explorer event series is created successfully but date is not as per my request.

below is json from graph explorer:

```
"start": {
            "dateTime": "2023-06-19T20:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2023-06-19T21:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },


"recurrence": {
            "pattern": {
                "type": "weekly",
                "interval": 1,
                "month": 0,
                "dayOfMonth": 0,
                "daysOfWeek": [
                    "monday",
                    "wednesday"
                ],
                "firstDayOfWeek": "sunday",
                "index": "first"
            },
            "range": {
                "type": "endDate",
                "startDate": "2023-06-19",
                "endDate": "2023-12-12",
                "recurrenceTimeZone": "UTC",
                "numberOfOccurrences": 0
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems to me correct. The first day for the event should be at Monday which is 2023-06-19, so the real startDate is 2023-06-19 not 2023-06-18. Graph API probably made some correction based on the pattern.